# How can I `Kernel.load` a file with a class definition in $SAFE = 1 under Ruby 1.9.2-p180?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use the two-argument form of `Kernel.load` while running in safe level 1 to load a class definition inside an anonymous namespace. For example, the file I'm trying to `Kernel.load` looks like:

```
# module.rb
class Foo < Superclass
    def bar
        puts "Bar!"
    end
end
```

And the test case looks like:

```
# loader.rb

BASEDIR = File.expand_path( File.dirname(__FILE__) )
MODULE_FILE = File.join( BASEDIR, 'module.rb' ).untaint

$stderr.puts "Module file name (%p) is %s" %
    [ MODULE_FILE, MODULE_FILE.tainted? ? "tainted" : "not tainted" ]

class Superclass
    @subclasses = []
    class << self; attr_reader :subclasses; end
    def self::inherited( subclass )
        super
        @subclasses << subclass
    end
end

$stderr.puts "Ruby version: #{RUBY_DESCRIPTION}"

$stderr.puts "In $SAFE = 0:"
Kernel.load( MODULE_FILE, true )
result = Superclass.subclasses.last
p result
$stderr.puts "Instantiating and calling its #bar method:"
result.new.bar

$stderr.puts "In $SAFE = 1:"
$SAFE = 1
Kernel.load( MODULE_FILE, true )
result = Superclass.subclasses.last
p result
$stderr.puts "Instantiating and calling its #bar method:"
result.new.bar
```

When I run it under Ruby 1.8.7, the output looks like:

```
Module file name ("/Users/mgranger/source/ruby/misc/safeload/module.rb") is not tainted
Ruby version: ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
In $SAFE = 0:
#<Module:0x1001688d8>::Foo
Instantiating and calling its #bar method:
Bar!
In $SAFE = 1:
#<Module:0x100168090>::Foo
Instantiating and calling its #bar method:
Bar!
```

but under 1.9.2, I get a SecurityError:

```
Module file name ("/Users/mgranger/source/ruby/misc/safeload/module.rb") is not tainted
Ruby version: ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]
In $SAFE = 0:
#<Module:0x0000010086b5b8>::Foo
Instantiating and calling its #bar method:
Bar!
In $SAFE = 1:
loader.rb:29:in `load': Insecure operation - load (SecurityError)
    from loader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

The documentation in the latest Pickaxe, and on [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001417) say `Kernel.load` does the following:

> ```
> load(filename, wrap=false) → true
> ```
>
> Loads and executes the Ruby program in the file filename. If the filename does not resolve to an absolute path, the file is searched for in the library directories listed in $:. If the optional wrap parameter is true, the loaded script will be executed under an anonymous module, protecting the calling program‘s global namespace. In no circumstance will any local variables in the loaded file be propagated to the loading environment.

If I replace the class definition with a `puts` or something, it loads fine, so that seems to be the problem. I'm not sure what changed in 1.9.2 and what I need to do differently to achieve the same effect. Any ideas?